# Model Key Path not found in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, macos

In a project in XCode V8.2, using objective-c, I have created an object with a couple of properties. When I want to create a binding and start entering the property in "Model Key Path", IB shows me all available properties as expected and I can select the desired one. All is well.
On another Mac however, running XCode V9.2, this process does not work. I can enter a Model Key Path and the app compiles and runs without errors, but IB does not show me the available properties when I start entering the property name. When the name is complete (and correct), IB shows me a grey exclamation mark and a hint that it cannot find the Model Key Path.
Does XCode V9.2 and up require different/additional steps for this?

Comment: Is this the same project, the same binding and the same key path?

Comment: It's broken for Xcode10 as well... I cannot even remember the last time this thing worked as supposed to. We could press Apple to go ahead and fix it via bug reporting but if I had to guess, I would not be surprised if something completely new arrives as a replacement (for bindings in general)

Comment: @Willeke, yes, same project, same code.

Comment: Xcode tries to resolve the key path but isn't very good at it, this has always been the case. In many cases it's impossible to resolve the key path and I think Xcode just gives up trying.

Comment: Well, eventually the paths _are_ resoveld because the app runs perfectly when compiled in both XCode 8.2 and XCode 9.2. It's just that during design time, the interface builder cannot resolve them in 9.2.

Comment: At runtime the paths are resolved by the Cocoa framework, not by Xcode. The key path checking feature of IB has always been hit and miss.